# How to remove JSON keys which not exists in another table?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables A and B.

Table A: the json_column **key** is valid if it exists in Table B's **json_key** with **a_id** matches its record's **id**.

```
+----+------------------------------+
| id |         json_column          |
+----+------------------------------+
|  1 | {"a": "value", "b": "value"} |
|  2 | {"a": "value", "c": "value"} |
+----+------------------------------+
```

Table B: **a_id** is the foreign key to Table A's **id**.

```
+------+----------+
| a_id | json_key |
+------+----------+
|    1 | a        |
|    2 | b        |
|    2 | c        |
+------+----------+
```

I'm trying to remove all invalid JSON keys from **json_column**. How can I do that?

Comment: Unpivot JSON to separate values, join 2nd table (non-existing keys will be skipped), reconstruct JSON back.

Comment: @Akina, thankyou, I will try it.